# Database schemas in PhpStorm not listed

Tags: mysql, database, schema, phpstorm

Sorry for my English....

I have database (MySql) connection established under PhpStorm. Database located on the network on a Ubuntu server. The connection works and I can send SQL commands, getting the results. But do not get table list "DB schema" appears. Why is that and what should I do?

[image: screenshot]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great that you added a screenshot! Have you tried clicking refresh or just double-clicking the hostname? I remember that I found it confusing as well.

Comment: i restarted PHP-Storm, do refresh und double-clicking the hostname... nothing help

Comment: In the "Data Sources and Drivers" menu, is there anything listed in "Schemas" for you data source?

Comment: yes, all databases on this server. My database is checked.

Comment: Please show screenshot of what you see on "Schemas" tab

Comment: i'm added new screanshot

Comment: 1) DO NOT remove previous screenshots please -- they may still be useful. 2) My only guess so far is that happens because you have a dot in DB names -- `jury.t3` and IDE does not handle such cases right.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have a dot in database name.

There is a bug in IDE that prevents such databases from showing up in the actual Database view -- it is [now fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-1486).

As I understand the fix should be available since PhpStorm **v2016.2** only. If you wish -- you my try [2016.2 EAP build](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/05/phpstorm-2016-2-eap/) right now.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly view this picture. I hope it may help you a little bit. May be you missed to give the database name. Also check the other options.

1. Database: Put your database name here.
   This database schema will display in your schema

[image]